# import all classes in a python file by a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

I am trying to use a for-loop to import classes defined within a python file.

Let us say we have file structure like this :

```
data
  -- data_sql
         -- __init__.py
         -- sqlFuncs.py
  -- data_web
         -- __init__.py
         -- webFuncs.py
```

and in `sqlFuncs.py` I defined several classess :

```
class sqlFuncBase:
      blabla
class sqlFuncChild1 (sqlFuncBase):
      blabla
class sqlFuncChild2 (sqlFuncBase):
      blabla
```

I have known that if I want to import one single class defined in `sqlFuncs.py`, I could use `from data.data_sql.sqlFuncs import sqlFuncBase as sqlBase` .

Now I want to import all defined classes in `sqlFuncs.py`. I have managed to get all classes defined in `sqlFuncs.py` by

```
    import data.data_sql.sqlFuncs
    mycls_lst = []
    for mcls in inspect.getmembers(data.data_sql.sqlFuncs, inspect.isclass) :
        if mcls[1].__module__ and mcls[1].__module__ == 'data.data_sql.sqlFuncs' :
            mycls_lst.append(mcls[1])
```

After that `mycls_lst` is a List of class whose type is of `abc.ABCMeta` aand if you check those element, for example, by `mycls_lst[0].__name__`, it is actually a string of that class name : `'sqlFuncBase'` (Note: there is no package prefix `'data.data_sql.sqlFuncs'`in this string). **However**, if I want to for-loop this list to import every class by :

```
for mcls in mycls_lst :
    from data.data_sqlFuncs import mcls as curr_cls
        # do something of this imported class
```

I will get errors : 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mcls'`

So, my question is how to for-loop import all self-defined classess in a python file ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use `from data.data_sql.sqlFuncs import *`?

Comment: What are you trying to do, i guess *import all classes in a python file by a for loop* isnt your real problem.